# Dask: Convex Matrix Optimization

Tags: dask

I am currently trying to implement Dask for a convex matrix optimization. The goal is to perform matrix optimization (factorization) on out-of-memory matrices. With a tall matrix as input and two tall matrices as output, along with some parameters (such as convergence etc.) I use dask array to chunk up my original matrix and itermediate/output matrices. Finally, the iterations are sequential in the sense that the output of the previous iteration is used as input in a new iteration (see simple example below).

At every iteration two criteria have to be calculated and checked for convergence (final if statement). However, what I see if I perform the code as given below is that Dask computes the criteria (as is enforced by the if-statement), but then recalculates the other matrices over every iteration: i.e. iteration 1 the criteria are calculated correctly, iteration 2 doesn't use the previously found A and E, but recalculates them, resulting in two SVD evaluations and so on. Dask doesn't seem to recognize the fact that  A_hat and E_hat were already calculated in the previous iteration, and then recalculates those values from the start. Or visa versa, it recalculates all steps for the criteria.

Persisting those matrices in-memory is also not an option, as they build up in memory over time. I saw similar optimizations in the blogposts (https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/03/22/dask-glm-1 and http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/04/19/dask-glm-2), but there it seems to be possible in every iteration to get the results in-memory, while for my optimization that isn't possible. I tried different set-ups, where I persisted some values or played with synchronous and asynchronous persisting and computing.

My question is hence, how can I keep the matrices (A and E, and by extension Y) from being computed and placed in-memory every iteration, while computing some norms on them at the end of each iteration? I had some ideas of using futures instead, or explicitly delay all the individual steps. Would one of those be a solution to my problem or are there more efficient ways?

Thanks in advance,

Roger

```js
def PCP(D, lambda_i, kmax):
    
    # Initialize norms
    normD = (norm(D, 'fro')).compute()
    normD2 = (norm(D, 2)).compute()
    normDinf = (norm(D.ravel(), np.inf)).compute()

    # Initialize Y
    Y = (1/np.maximum(normD2, (1/lambda_i)*normDinf))*D

    # Initialize A and A_hat
    A = da.zeros_like(D)
    A_hat = da.zeros_like(D)
    
    # Initialize E and E_hat
    E = da.zeros_like(D)
    E_hat = da.zeros_like(D)

    # Initialize mu: mu_0 > 0
    mu = 1.25/normD2 # Convergence Rate

    # Initialize rho: rho > 1
    rho = 1.6 # Convergence Rate

    runAlgorithm = True
    k = 0
    while runAlgorithm:
        
        # Estimate E_hat
        E_hat = da.maximum((D-A+(1/mu)*Y)-(1/mu)*lambda_i, 0)+da.minimum((D-A+(1/mu)*Y)+(1/mu)*lambda_i, 0)
        
        # Estimate A_hat
        Q = da.linalg.svd(D-E_hat+(1/mu)*Y)
        svp = (Q[1] - 1/mu).clip(0)
        A_hat = (Q[0]*svp)@Q[2]
        
        # Update Y
        Y = Y+mu*(D-A_hat-E_hat)
        
        # Calculate stopping criteria
        crit1 = norm(D-A_hat-E_hat, 'fro')/normD
        crit2 = norm(E-E_hat, 'fro')/normD
        
        # Update A and E
        A = A_hat
        E = E_hat
        
        # Check if Converged
        if k == kmax or crit1 < 0.01 or crit2 < 0.01:
            runAlgorithm = False
    
        k = k + 1
        

    return  A, E, k, crit1, crit2
```

I use the following dask distributed settings:

```
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
client = Client(threads_per_worker=4,
            n_workers=1, memory_limit='4GB')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I'll say some general things here that you may know already.

If you can fit some results in memory, then you should consider calling `persist` on those parts to avoid repeated work.  If you can't fit them in memory, then I'm not sure what can be done here.  Making efficient algorithms like what you describe above is a lot about figuring out which parts of the computation you need to keep around as small state, and which parts you will need to recompute every time.

As an example, you might want to take a look at the [matrix algorithms in dask-glm](https://github.com/dask/dask-glm/blob/master/dask_glm/algorithms.py), which perform this dance effectively.